# Get count of records in source and sink in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, count, copy, azure-data-factory

Can someone tell me how to get source and sink count in Azure Data Factory after data copy activity? My source and sink are SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information from the output JSON of the Copy Activity. Just add an activity following your Copy in the pipeline and you can store the values in a variable or use a data flow to transform and persist the data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mark for the response. I need to write these details to a metadata table in sql server. Can you please tell me how to do that . I am new to Azure Data factory.

Comment: I tried creating 2 variables , i am able to store count in the variables after that if i am using lookup to insert values through query into meta data table of sql server it is failing with the error "Variables is not a recognized built-in function"

Comment: How about using a stored procedure?

Comment: I used parameters instead of variables and  inserting using lookup , but now it says invalid sql query.  ErrorCode=SqlInvalidDbQueryString, 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The specified SQL Query is not valid. It could be caused by that the query doesn't return any data. Invalid query: 'insert into dbo.SourceTargetCount(source_count,target_count) values(1000,1000);if @@TRANCOUNT>0  commit;',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Lookup1",
    "details": []
}

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT is it possible to see how many rows were inserted vs updated?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mark, you can use the copy activity output to store in a variable and pass that variable to a stored procedure to insert that value in a table.

[image: Copy_data passing source records read to stored procedure]

Answer (score 0):

May be too late to answer but could help someone.

In may case (reading file from HDFS) I have enabled `Import Schema` from the `Mapping` section of the `Copy data` activity and that has enabled the `rowsRead` and `rowsCopied` attributes in the json output

[image]

[image]

Note: rowsRead and rowsCopied won't present by default